# How to let ruby and maven work together

Tags: java, ruby, maven

I have a project written by java via maven. And I found some modules can be implemented via Ruby, because ruby is strong in script. So, I want to merge the ruby scripts into maven file structure. But where should I put these ruby scripts folder in maven file structure? Anything recommend?

Comment: I'd recommend you try [jruby](https://github.com/jruby/jruby/wiki/Using-JRuby-with-Maven).